# How do I resolve two conflicting JQuery library?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I used [this code](https://codepen.io/Palestinian/details/dPYJam/) as a tutorial in my project to enable mobile **swipe to reveal** functionality.

On its own it works perfectly as per code tutorial, I am able to successfully swipe left to reveal the **More**, **Flag** and the **Trash** buttons, while swiping right reverses the process by hiding the **More**, **Flag** and the **Trash** buttons as seen in the image below.

[image: The Swipe to reveal function in my project working perfectly]

Following are the the projects `js` dependecies:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

...along with its `css` files:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css'>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I then found this [push and reveal panel](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/panels/#panel-open) functionality that I thought I would add to my project, again on its on it works perfectly:

Following are the [push and reveal panel](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/panels/#panel-open) dependencies:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

...along with its css files:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/_assets/css/jqm-demos.css'>
```

After combining them in my project I noticed that the two dependecies seem to be conflicting, because my **swipe to reveal** functionality doesnt look the same, and I am **not** able to swipe any more. The image below is illustrates what it currently looks like:

[image: The Swipe to reveal UI distored and the swipe not working anymore]

Find below the `js` dependecies after combining the project:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

..along with its `css` files:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css'>
```

Comment: Best strategy: do not use two conflicting versions of jQuery.

Comment: Yikes on the last time that library was updated.

Comment: @Pointy Any idea on how I can get my project to run though?

Comment: @epascarello Any idea on how I can get my project to run though?

Comment: use the noconflit from jquery itself: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Wasn't jQuery Mobile depreciated last year?  See: https://blog.jquery.com/2021/10/07/jquery-maintainers-continue-modernization-initiative-with-deprecation-of-jquery-mobile/

Comment: No conflict is not magically going to fix stylesheet. Hopefully you could just use the 1.4 version of everything and it will work. But you are using something that is not supported and 8+ years old.

Comment: I'd suggest migrating away from jQuery mobile fully. It is outdated, no longer supported and, frankly, wasn't very good to start with.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Bummer! Is there an alternative to creating something more mobile-friendly in User Interface?

Comment: Back in 2010 when jQm was first released there was a need for a mobile-centric UI library, this isn't the case any more. As such, there's no specific library which handles it. Mobile devices are now perfectly capable of rendering HTML content clearly. All you really need is to implement CSS media queries. If you do want to use a library, then Bootstrap or Material would be my suggestions